# Android layout editor error

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am facing error when i try to view graphical layout of XML.
I get following error in Error Log.

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ROOT at
>   android.util.LocaleUtil.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(LocaleUtil.java:60)
>   at
>   android.content.res.Configuration.updateFrom(Configuration.java:507)
>   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.updateConfiguration(Resources.java:1450)
>   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.updateConfiguration(Resources.java:1408)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.(Resources.java:205) at
>   android.content.res.Resources.(Resources.java:185) at
>   android.content.res.BridgeResources.(BridgeResources.java:118)
>   at
>   android.content.res.BridgeResources.initSystem(BridgeResources.java:97)
>   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.initResources(BridgeContext.java:155)
>   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.setUp(RenderAction.java:227)
>   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.init(RenderAction.java:121)
>   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.init(RenderSessionImpl.java:165)
>   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:320)
>   at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
>   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
>   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1317)
>   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1071)
>   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:897)
>   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(LayoutEditor.java:384)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:291)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:228)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1027) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1012) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:770) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3256)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:2045) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:323)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3910)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3503)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369) at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221) at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)

I have attached the screen shot.I tried to search the solution of this issue.
Some where it was said to update the java.I have also updated the Java.

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to restart the eclipse and open this layout by right click on it->open with->Android Layout Editor.

Comment: can you put the xml file pls?